# Taking list of dict as function argument from cmd python

Tags: bash, shell, python

I am trying to execute gunicorn server in which I have to pass list of dict as input. But when I am sending empty string as value it's removed.
My command is

```
import subprocess
cmd = """gunicorn 'myapp:create([{key: ""}])' --worker-class gevent -w 1 --bind 127.0.0.1:8019"""
subprocess.call([cmd], shell=True)
```

Inside myapp

```
#myapp.py
create(d_input):
    print(d_input)
    # OUT : [{key: }]
```

As you can see `''` are eliminated so I am unable to parse list & dict. Is there any way to avoid this.

I have also tried passing input something like `[{key : 'Something'}]` in this case output is `[{key : Something}]` whereas I expect `[{key : 'Something'}]`.
Any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered same issue converting list to json solved this for me.

```
import subprocess
cmd = """gunicorn 'myapp:create(json.dumps([{key: ""}]))' --worker-class gevent -w 1 --bind 127.0.0.1:8019"""
subprocess.call([cmd], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you need a shell for this. Try

```bsh
cmd = ["gunicorn", 'myapp:create([{key: ""}])', "--worker-class", "gevent", "-w", "1", "--bind", "127.0.0.1:8019"]
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
```